# What are flags and mask parameters does in getWindow().setFlags(int flags, int mask)?

Tags: android

I know that

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

will hide the title bar of an activity. But at android does this function written as

```
getWindow().setFlags(int flags, 
                int mask)
```

But I want to know what are those flags and mask actually means? What is the use of those in android applications?

Comment: Are you asking for a list of acceptable values?

Comment: No, I want to what are those flags and mask are actually means?
Where those are use in android applications?

Comment: Ok - I still am not sure what you are asking but hopefully someone else understands and can field your question